# Dual 2560x1600 resolution on the intel Haswell NUCs

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, displayport, haswell

Do the [current 4th generation intel NUC kits](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/overview.html) support driving a 2560x1600 ([WQHD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution)) resolution to two such monitors at the same time in extended desktop mode (not cloning one display)?

As an example, this [NUC D54250WYKH](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/nuc-kit-d54250wykh-brief.pdf) has a Mini DisplayPort 1.2 and a Mini HDMI 1.4 port. The specifications of those interfaces would allow to drive 2560x1600 each. The built in intel cpu has a HD Graphics 5000, the Display port is guaranteed to drive 4K displays and multi monitor solutions, but there's no testament to the capabilities of the HDMI output.

Most of the 2560x1600 (or 2560x1440) monitors do not accept their native resolution on HDMI inputs. For example the [Dell U2711](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_Display/dell-u2711_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf) accepts its native resolution on DVI and DisplayPort only, not on its HDMI input, as described on page 33 of the manual "Set the screen resolution to 2560 x 1440 (DVI and DisplayPort) or 2048 x 1152 (VGA) or 1080p (HDMI, Component).". The [Samsung SyncMaster 27A850DS](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/computer-peripherals/monitors/commercial/LS27A850DS/XK-spec?subsubtype=sa650-and-sa850-led) does not even have HDMI inputs and accepts its native 2560x1440 on either of 2 Dual Link DVI or the Display Port.

On a side note: This older 3rd generation [NUC DC53427](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-kit-dc53427hye.html) has two Mini Displayports and one mini HDMI ports. While its manual does not explicitly list support for the dual WQHD resolution on the two Display Ports it does not restrict them either. If all three ports are in use, the three monitors can be driven to 3 times Full HD (1920x1080). This implies that there might be a restriction on driving two WQHD displays at the same time on the two Display Ports.

intel FAQs related to this topic are the [Standard Graphics FAQ](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031026.htm) and the [3 Monitor setup FAQ](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-031040.htm). The 3 Monitor FAQ is very specific on combinations of resolution, but the 2 monitor/extended display FAQ is not.

I would need to run the system with both Windows 8 and Linux, but if any one of these would drive the dual WQHD resolution on the NUC hardware, that would be valuable information.

Comment: 5th Generation NUCs based on "Broadwell" seem to be able to do it. [Table 9 on page 25 of the Vol1. Datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/5th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.html) lists several combinations involving WQHD even on all 3 display ports (in combinations 2*HDMI+1*eDP, or 2*DP+1*eDP). If the systems manufacturer adds level shifters on the HDMI ports, even 2*4K resolutions can be output (but only at 24Hz). Now, after the long wait, I only have to test that in reality. :^]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Technical Product Specifications](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/23089/eng/D54250WYB_D34010WYB_TechProdSpec05.pdf) document from Intel (Page 23), it shows a bit more detail.  In particular, when using both the mini-DP and HDMI you are limited to 1920x1200 via HDMI.  You can do full resolution if you daisy chain off the mini-DP to two monitors.

In my testing, I wouldn't feel comfortable using the product for those resolutions.  In testing 4k and multi-monitor configs, the machine gets pretty hot and performance isn't that great for non-static content.